# DOM not being updated when the value of a controller variable changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have an AngularJS app that relies on data stored within Local Storage.

Within my app there is a list of stations displayed, ordered by when they were lask clicked.  When the user clicks on any of these stations the Local Storage is updated (successfully) using the `update` method in the `$recentStations` service below, and the list of stations is updated on screen.

My issue though is that the I display the most recent station in the header of the site, and this is not updated automatically when the user clicks on a station.

How can I amend my code to fix this?

---

## Service

```
app.factory('$recentStations', ['$localStorage', function($localStorage){

    var recentStations = {
    
        local : $localStorage.$default({    
            recentStations: []
        }),
        
        get : function(){
            return this.local.recentStations;
        },
        
        getCurrent : function(){
            return this.local.recentStations[0];
        },
        
        update : function(elm){
            this.local.recentStations.unshift(elm);
        }
        
    };
        
    return recentStations;
    
}]);
```

---

## Controller

```
app.controller('headerCtrl', ['$scope', '$recentStations', function($scope, $recentStations){

    $scope.currentStation = $recentStations.getCurrent();
    
}]);
```

---

## HTML

```
<div id="header" data-ng-controller="headerCtrl">

    <div class="inner">
    
        <h1 data-ng-if="currentStation">
            <span class="orange">Tiger</span> | {{ currentStation.name }} ({{ (currentStation.code | uppercase) }})</span>
        </h1>
        
        <h1 data-ng-if="!currentStation"><span class="orange">Tiger</span> | Select a station</h1>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your controller is constructed, it asks the current station to the service and stores it in a scope variable. But when you update the current station in the service, the scope variable still references the initial current station. Not the new one. So you need to always get the current station from the service instead of caching it in the scope:

Instead of

```
$scope.currentStation = $recentStations.getCurrent();
```

Use

```
$scope.getCurrentStation = function() {
    return $recentStations.getCurrent();
}
```

And in the view, instead of `currentStation`, use `getCurrentStation()`. That way, every time the view refreshes itself, it calls the service to get the most recent station.

Or, when the current station is modified, broadcast an event on the rootscope to alert your controller that it should reload the current station.

Note that you should NOT name your own services `$xxx`. The `$` prefix is precisely used as a namespace for services provided by the framework, to make sure any newly introduced service in the framework doesn't clash with one of yours.

Comment: Thank you, your answer works (although I'm not sure as to why?). And thanks for the tip regarding naming of services; I did that for continuity, but I can easily remove instances of `$`.

Comment: I have added a paragraph at the top of my answer to explain why your code doesn't work and why mine works.

Comment: Got it - so basically setting a variable directly in the `Scope` caches it, but returning it via a function ensures that it's always updated. Thanks for the help.